# Ping members with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, ping

I am making a command for my bot that will DM members when the command is used `+ping @Member` . Here is my code:

```
    if message.content.startswith('+ping'):
        ping = message.content.replace("+ping ","")
        dm_member = ping
        pinger = message.author
        await dm_member.send('You got pinged by:')
        await dm_member.send(pinger)
```

But in return I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 95, in on_message
    await dm_member.send('You got pinged by:')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

How do I fix this AttributeError?

When I replace `dm_member` with `message.author` (therefore pinging the author) it works.

**I think it doesn't work because str objects don't have discord attributes. But how can I fix this?**

Comment: You set `dm_member` equal to `ping` which is a string (str object). Use pinger.send instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    if message.content.startswith('+ping'):
        ping = message.content.replace("+ping ","")
        user_id = int(ping[2:-1]) # convert to int
        dm_member = await message.guild.get_member(user_id) # this function accepts an int
        pinger = message.author
        await dm_member.send('You got pinged by:')
        await dm_member.send(pinger)
```

You set `dm_member` equal to `ping` which is a string, a Python built-in. `pinger` is the user object of the author. To get the pinged user, extract the user id from `ping` and use it to find the user object using `await message.guild.get_member(user_id)`.

Comment: Thanks. But there's one thing: this will dm the person who is pinging the user, or the "pinger". ```dm_member``` is the person (taken from the message, removing the command). Is it possible to make this string… not a string? Because message.author would DM the user.

Comment: @iamultron then you could do `await message.guild.get_member(user id)` to fetch the user object. If you mention a user on Discord, the bot sees "<@user id>" and you can use this to get the user id. I'll edit the answer accordingly

Comment: Will the bot need guild permissions to use the `message.guild.get_member` line?